# Embed SU(2) into SO(6) or SU(4)

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, tensor-decomposition

Here is a pattern of group embedding, 
$$
SU(4) \supset SU(3) \times U(1)
$$
such that the irrep of SU(4) can be decomposed as the sum of tensor product of irrep of SU(3) and irrep of U(1).

[image]

> Two questions:
>
> - I wonder what will be the embedding for SO(6),
>     $$
>   SO(6) \supset SU(2) \times G,
>   $$
>     where, such that the irrep of SO(6) can be decomposed as the sum of tensor product of irrep of SU(2) and irrep of $G$?
> - alternatively
>     what will be the embedding for $Spin(6)\simeq SU(4)$,
>     $$
>   Spin(6)\simeq SU(4) \supset SU(2) \times G',
>   $$
>     where, such that the irrep of SU(4) can be decomposed as the sum of tensor product of irrep of SU(2) and irrep of $G'$?

I only ask the proper ways to write the group $G$ and $G'$ here.

Here $G$ and $G'$ may be a product of several groups.

Comment: you want to find all the possible $G$ and $G'$ on the right hand sides?

Comment: yes! please help